# Chromedriver and Chrome doesn't seem to be working with Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I don't understand what the issue is. I'm trying to open chrome using selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver

site = 'https://www.google.com'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(site)
```

when I run it there is no activity, no chrome window.

I have the chromedriver.exe inside the scripts folder in python directory. It worked couple of hours ago when I first tried it but now for some reason it seemed to stop working.

Both chromedriver and chrome updated to the latest and the same version (114).

Comment: [Check this to see how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If your code worked before you can start from the beginning or retrace your steps till it works. Since the question you asked is too vague, all I can do is provide similar answer - [try providing executable path](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/blob/trunk/examples/python/tests/drivers/test_service.py#L12), [try using webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/), [use time.sleep()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sleep-in-python/),

Answer (score 0):

Check the *Task Manager* for the currently running processes. There may be a lot of ***Zombie / Orphan*** [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) instances having entry in the process table to report to its parent process.

Kill those [***Zombie / Orphan***](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zombie-and-orphan-processes-in-c/) ***ChromeDriver*** instances and execute your test.